# Rundeck Windows job always successful

Tags: rundeck

I'm using Rundeck version 3.4.0 installed on Centos 8 server.

I installed WinRM Node Executor Python plugin version 2.0.12 to run jobs on a Windows 2016 server.

A simple .bat job that tries to delete files on my Windows server is always Successful, even if the file does not exist.

However, in the log file I have the error 'Could Not Find C:...'

Same job running on a Linux server with ssh fails when the file doesn't exist.

I precise that I'm really new with Rundeck.

The very simple .bat file :

```
:: Rundeck delete file
:: 
@ECHO OFF
del C:\users\winrmuser\Documents\CreateFile_%1.log
EXIT
```

And the job definition :

```
- <joblist>
- <job>
  <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab> 
  <description /> 
- <dispatch>
  <excludePrecedence>true</excludePrecedence> 
  <keepgoing>false</keepgoing> 
  <rankOrder>ascending</rankOrder> 
  <successOnEmptyNodeFilter>false</successOnEmptyNodeFilter> 
  <threadcount>1</threadcount> 
  </dispatch>
  <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled> 
  <id>9c33bba8-223a-4f55-9a71-16b239eac465</id> 
  <loglevel>INFO</loglevel> 
  <name>Test horus delete file</name> 
  <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable> 
- <nodefilters>
  <filter>horus</filter> 
  </nodefilters>
  <nodesSelectedByDefault>true</nodesSelectedByDefault> 
- <notification>
- <onfailure>
  <email attachLog="true" attachLogInFile="true" recipients="xxx@yyy.zzz" /> 
  </onfailure>
- <onsuccess>
  <email attachLog="true" attachLogInFile="true" recipients="xxx@yyy.zzz" /> 
  </onsuccess>
  </notification>
  <notifyAvgDurationThreshold /> 
  <plugins /> 
  <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled> 
- <sequence keepgoing="false" strategy="node-first">
- <command>
  <description>DeleteFile</description> 
  <exec>C:\Users\winrmuser\Documents\RundeckDeleteFile.bat New</exec> 
- <plugins>
- <LogFilter type="key-value-data">
- <config>
  <invalidKeyPattern>\s|\$|\{|\}|\\</invalidKeyPattern> 
  <logData>false</logData> 
  <name>DeleteFailed</name> 
  <regex>^RUNDECK:DATA:\s*([^\s]+?)\s*=\s*(.+)$</regex> 
  </config>
  </LogFilter>
- <LogFilter type="highlight-output">
- <config>
  <bgcolor>red</bgcolor> 
  <fgcolor>green</fgcolor> 
  <mode>bold</mode> 
  <regex>failed</regex> 
  </config>
  </LogFilter>
  </plugins>
  </command>
  </sequence>
  <uuid>9c33bba8-223a-4f55-9a71-16b239eac465</uuid> 
  </job>
  </joblist>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi! Could you share an minimal reproducible example? Maybe the script and the rundeck job definition? I tested and it works as expected. A .bat file example: https://pastebin.com/imyueeeP and the result if the file doesn't exist: https://imgur.com/D1Q1d7X

Comment: Could you, please, give me your definition file ?

Comment: Hello, it work now, but I have to modify my Batch job :

Comment: :: Rundeck delete file
:: 
@ECHO OFF

dir "C:\users\winrmuser\Documents\CreateFile_%1.log"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
 del C:\users\winrmuser\Documents\CreateFile_%1.log
 echo successful
) else (
EXIT
)

Comment: Good! Please add your solution as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

it work now, but I have to modify my Batch job : : Rundeck delete file :: @ECHO OFF dir "C:\users\winrmuser\Documents\CreateFile_%1.log" IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 ( del C:\users\winrmuser\Documents\CreateFile_%1.log echo successful ) else ( EXIT )